# While loop does not stop iterating through array

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I have a php file in which I created a class Bank - has 2 methods - first one produces 5 users and populates random transactions in the database
The second one should display the balance of the users.

I've searched on the site and no one had such an example on here.

I've successfully connected to database and wrote a (not a really good) query to fetch me all data from both tables.

`$query = "SELECT * FROM users, transactions";`

The problem I'm facing is that I'm not that good at php and the syntax is driving me crazy - my while loop loops through the result that the query produces but it does not stop after it goes through all the result rows in the array - it just repeats itself endlessly.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'ipromapp', '3306');

class Bank
{
    function balance() 
    {
        global $connection;

        if($connection)
        {
            echo ("Connection online<br>");
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users, transactions";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysql_error());

        echo "<table border='1px'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> ID </td>";
        echo "<td> Name </td>";
        echo "<td> Balance </td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $id = $row[0];
            $name = $row[1];
            $balance = $row[2];

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td> {$id} </td>";
            echo "<td> {$name} </td>";
            echo "<td> {$balance} </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
$bank = new Bank;
$bank->randomize();
$bank->balance();
```

The results are as following ( there are 5 users in the database atm ) http://prntscr.com/mf6edg

It just goes and goes.

I'm 100% it is the while loop but I don't have the knowledge about how to change the condition inside it, if one would be kind enough to please help me out.

Comment: The problem is the query, written like that it will generate all those results. Run it in `phpMyAdmin` or some similiar tool and you will see

Comment: just bcoz of `transactions` table, using `JOIN` will help here.

Comment: "The problem I'm facing is that I'm not that good at php and the syntax is driving me crazy" – I don't see any problem with the syntax. Can you explain what specific problems you have with the syntax? Or, why you believe it is a syntactical problem and not a semantic one?

Comment: Thanks guys for help, I'm sorry if I insulted anyone with my writing - It is not my intention here. I'm just trying to learn and sometimes I don't have anyone else to turn to but online forums and strangers that are helpful. It was the query - I was able to find the right one to do the things I wanted thanks to @scaisEdge answer mostly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will select all the rows of the second  table for each row of the first table (your select produces a cartesian product).

Assuming your tables  are  related  by a key eg: user_id you should try a join

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM users u 
  INNER JOIN  transactions t  on u.user_id =  t.user_id
```

in this way you should obtain only transaction related to the specific user_id

Comment: This helped a ton! Thank you kind sir!